# Running a java program multiple times from command prompt

Tags: java, multithreading

If i run a same multithreaded program from multiple command prompt, what would happen? Each command prompt will run in diffrent jvm. how the shared resources will access by threads in different jvm?

Comment: Define _shared resources_. JVMs don't share state.

Comment: What shared resources?

Comment: are you talking about Shared Resources in Multithreading or for multiple programs,don't get confused both are different prospects.

Comment: i think you are confused between multithreading and multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

> If i run a same multithreaded program from multiple command prompt,
>   what would happen?

there is seperate JVM for each program or application. (whether application is same or different)

> how the shared resources will access by threads in different jvm?

As Same multithreaded application is executed by different JVM there is nothing(resources) to share by different JVM's.
As there are different java application are running same time(multiprocessing) shared resources of machine(memory , processor etc.) are handled by OS.

Note:IF you are asking about shared resources in single multithreaded application please refer [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JVM isn't doing voodoo magic (knowing Oracle I can't be sure) each instance of Java would be running it's own thing and allocating it's own resources. As for how the host handles threading and resource distribution is a whole nother subject with tons of discussion and no good answer on how to do it (other than "Correctly")

Answer (score 0):

To share resources among different JVM you need an external player, a [Redis](http://redis.io/) DB or similar, however if your program is multithread, why do you need to run different process ? Why don't you run it just one time ?

Answer (score 0):

Each command prompt will run in diffrent jvm - Yes.
Among different jvms Resource sharing will be  decided by operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If two instances of JVM run the same multi threaded application, you cannot do resource sharing. Remember, resource sharing and concurrency control is between multiple threads running a single JVM process. Two such JVM processes, running the same application code, cannot do any concurrency control and resource sharing. For example, if the first JVM process opens a file, the second JVM process will not be able to access that file.
I hope this answers your question. If there is something specific which you are trying, then describe that, so that, we can offer you suggestions.